# Why do I I get null point exception even though I safeguarded against it?

Tags: android, kotlin, null

How do I safeguard against null points? I tried this way:

```
var spr = context.getSharedPreferences("FAV", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
var emptyArray: JsonArray = jsonArray()
var myjson = spr.getString("KEY", null)

//GET JSON FROM SHARED PREFERENCE

Log.d("TAG", "NOT NULL")
if(myjson != null) {
    var parsedFavFromJson = Gson().fromJson<List<String>>(myjson)
    //PARSE FROM JSON TO ARRAY

    for (i in parsedFavFromJson) {
        emptyArray.add(i)
        Log.d("TAG", "" + i)

        if (i == recipeArray!![counterX].recipeKey!!) {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(R.drawable.fav_icon_60at3x).into(favMarkerButton)
            Log.d("TAG", "Match " + i)
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "WAS NULL")
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(R.drawable.fav_unclicked_icon60at3x).into(favMarkerButton)
        }
    }
}
```

I have clearly stated the conditional `if(myjson != null)`, still it pass through and crash with the error message `java.lang.IllegalStateException: fromJson(json, typeToken<T>()) must not be null`. There is no clear indication where the error actually occur - it actually points to an empty code line! If I remove the code above, things are working fine. I also tried using:

```
var myjson = spr.getString("KEY", null).let {
```

...and so on, with the same result. Am I missing something here?

***UPDATE***
I checked variable `myjson` and it *is* clearly `null`. Question is why the conditional `if(myjson != null)` passed...

Comment: What safeguard? You have `!!` operator.

Comment: Please try to run a clean build and you find the line where the error is coming. Disable instant run if you using for now and try.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried removing the `!!` code and I still have the error. I also did a clean build, but I get the error links on the same places, completely unrelated to the code above...

Answer (score 0):

In short, you're missing the question mark.

You expect that in block:

```
spr.getString("KEY", null).let { it }
```

Won't be null? That's incorrect.

Correct syntax is

```
spr.getString("KEY", null)?.let { it }
```

Easy to miss.

Same goes for working with nested JSONs. You should never use bang-bang (`!!`) in Kotlin. Use the safe syntax instead:

```
recipeArray?[counterX].recipeKey
```

Comment: Thanks, but even with the question mark I get the very same error :/

Comment: From what you wrote, I suspect that you're having two different issues: one mentioned above, and the other of project not recompiling correctly. Please try removing the project and adding it again, as Android Studio / IntelliJ keep caches.